Op amp VCC- question
Currently I'm learning about op amps and am getting confused about something.
Changing the negative supply makes the op amp output not follow the equation for a non inverting op amp (gain = 1 + R1/R2)
When I use ground as a negative supply the output is in line with the equation, but when I switch to using -9 V as my negative supply (with +9 V as my positive supply) the output is not in line with the gain equation.
I'm not sure why this is for the circuit I am building, I need to amplify a voltage of around 50 µV with a TL072, so using ground as a negative supply isn't an option because (from what I have read) the input that is intended to be amplified must be above ~3 or ~4 V from the negative supply or the output will fly to the upper boundary, I believe this was called the "opamp phase inversion" problem.
I'm not sure what to do.
Here is a test circuit I am using to address my first concern:

As you can see, the output (which should be about 1.1 V as per the gain equation) is at 25 mV.
Here is the same circuit using +9V and GND as supplies with the same input (0.1 V).

As you can see the output is ~1.2 V, whilst still not exactly in line with the equation, this is much closer and in line with possible error of circuit simulation right?

Are you doing a simulation or testing a physical circuit? If it's a simulation, please share your schematic (for both cases of the V- connection). If a physical circuit, please share both the schematic and photographs of the physical circuit.

Can you show your non-inverting circuit that doesn’t work? Keep in mind that if you use a negative voltage for the negative supply rail, you still need to use ground for your feedback network.

added the requested photos to the question as per @ThePhoton request

This circuit is so simple that I would start with a breadboard. The simulation can inform something, but - as thousands of questions on this site show - simulation is often much harder to get right for beginners than real circuits are. Simulators lie profusely because they are meant to provide correct results when the circuits are roughly correct. Circuits that don't function in real life may do all sorts of things in a simulator. So it's a catch-22: you need to know how the working circuit should look in order to simulate it. Hard to do for a beginner, isn't it? Thus: breadboard!!

Is this a DC signal - a range form 0 to 50uV that you need to amplify, very slowly changing, or is it an AC signal, say audio, accelerometer measuring vibration, etc?

You have not built a " non inverting op amp" circuit - your R2 is in the wrong place.

You don't have a typical non-inverting amplifier circuit there. R1 is in the feedback loop, but R2 is on the output. You should have R2 on the other side of R1, from the inverting input to ground.
This is what the circuit should look like, note the positions of R1 and R2:

Also you say the gain is 1.1, but you have a 1 Ω and a 10 Ω resistors, with R2 wired correctly this would give a gain of
$$
1 + \frac{10}{1} = 11
$$
And those resistor values are pretty low which can take more current than the opamp output can supply. Typically you would use higher values, try it with something like 100 Ω and 1k, or 1k and 10k.
Update:
My simulation was done with a bipolar supply, which is where you said you were running into problems. Note that your single supply version wasn't correct either, and even when the resistors were corrected it still won't work with a 0.1 V input. Simulating with a 9 V single supply the input range for linear output is something like 200 mV to 7 V due to the TL072 not being a rail to rail opamp. If you want the input range to go down to zero you need a bipolar supply, with \$V_{EE}\$ being at least -1.7 V.

yes sorry, by "gain of 1.1" I meant output of about 1.1V with an input of 0.1V using the gain of 11. Not sure what you mean about this not being a typical non-inverting amplifier circuit though

@KPUGGaming Added an image of the way it should look.

@KPUGGaming Also, I tried it with 1 and 10 ohms, and I only got an output of a couple hundred millivolts because of the loading on the output. 1.1V through 11 ohms is 100 mA, the TL072 short circuit output current is only 26 mA. You have to keep that in mind when picking resistor values.

Sometimes I wish I can vote twice on your answers.

Simulators only simulate correct circuits well. It's a bit of catch-22. When the circuit is somehow fundamentally wrong, the simulator may do all sorts of creative things.
Why? Because the models used for simulation are by necessity simplified. They are meant to represent the behavior of real components when used within their intended operating range. Outside of that you're on your own. Thus, you probably should not be using a simulator, but play on a breadboard. The breadboard won't lie to you, for the most part. If stuff won't work, it really won't work, it's real life, not simulation :)

The problem with formulas like the non-inverting gain formula is that they apply to ideal op-amps. If you stick to the formula but use a non-ideal op-amp, then it's very easy to get a non-working circuit if you don't keep that non-ideal op-amp within its correct operating range.
For a TL072, feedback circuit elements must be on the order of kΩ to MΩ. That's because the output of that op-amp cannot really drive low impedances - it doesn't have enough "oomph" to do that.
So, your circuit with a 10 Ω feedback resistor will only work if the other feedback network resistor is 1kΩ or more. So you will get very low gain - say 1.01x.
To get a gain of 10 in a non-inverting op-amp circuit, you'd typically use a 9kΩ / 1kΩ network. If noise isn't a big concern but low power consumption and linearity are, you'd increase both of those resistances by a factor of 5x-50x, maintaining their ratio. If wideband noise has to be kept to a minimum, R1 should be around 1kΩ and then R2 can be smaller.
Using E96 (1%) resistors, you'd really use 9.09kΩ since there's no 9.00kΩ value in that series. With E192 (0.5%) resistors, you'd use 8.98kΩ - that's about 4x closer to 9.00 than 9.09 is.
Hobbyists usually have access to E24 series with tolerance around 1%. So, you'd use 8.2kΩ + 820Ω (in series) to get 9.0kΩ.


when I use ground as a negative supply the output is in line with the equation

It's not. TL072's common mode range goes down to about 2V above VCC-. Thus, with VCC- at 0V, and (+) at ≈50μV, the latter is outside the input common mode range. If the output is "in line" with anything, it does so by pure coincidence. Let's make it clear: a TL072 with (+)=(-VCC) does not work correctly.

when I switch to using -9V as my negative supply (with +9V as my positive supply) the output is not in line with the gain equation.

No, now most likely the TL072 is working as designed. TL072 has up to several mV of input offset. Thus, whatever tiny voltage you put on the input, has several mV of offset error added to it.
Since your input voltage is around 50μV, the offset error vastly exceeds the voltage you're measuring. Thus the op-amp may appear "not to work". But it actually does - it's just amplifying a sum of its offset error and your tiny input signal.

not sure what to do

You'll need to zero-out (null) the input offset error so that the voltage you're measuring will be much larger than the residual offset error. You can look up various techniques for offset adjustment.
If your signal is AC only, then you can configure the op-amp so that it has gain 1 at DC, and high gain only at AC. That's one way to pick out the 50μV signal out.
To make the gain AC-only with bipolar supply:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
At DC, only R2b conducts and sets overall gain to 2. At AC, C1 is a "short", and R2 is effectively R2a||R2b, where "||" means "in parallel with".
It is also possible to get gain when running from a single 9V supply. We do that by using a resistive divider R4-R5 to get a +4.5V  "virtual ground", then AC-couple the input to this "ground", same with the feedback network. The output signal will hover around 4.5V, but with gain applied.

simulate this circuit
To get a DC signal close to 0V amplified with a TL072 requires jumping through some hoops, with auxiliary circuits.
The main reason to use TL072 is to limit the input noise and improve "audio" performance over that of LM358. For DC applications, LM358 has less noise than TL072, although it may be a wash with some better TL072 examples. LM358 can operate from supply voltages as low as 3.0V, and that's quite handy with 3.3V digital supplies.
So, to get gain at low voltages, you'd be best served using modern op-amps designed for low-voltage operation - they will handily beat both TL072 and LM358 in almost every spec imaginable.
If you want to use 40-50 year-old parts (as 072 and 358 are!), will take some real design work. Textbook circuits will not work as-is, and you will be designing not for "textbook" op-amps, but for the real parts, with all their warts, while keeping the internal schematic of those op-amps in mind, since it heavily influences their non-ideal behavior.

LM358 doesn't have particularly low noise, but it can operate with both inputs at or slightly below the lower supply rail. So, amplifying 0-50μV around DC is certainly possible. LM358 is noisy, but it should still be usable at least to demonstrate the principle. You won't need to worry about using the full range of the ADC because of noise. So you can probably run that 358 from +3.3V and get all the performance you can get out of it.

Here's how I would do an LM358-based "50μV DC" amplifier in a 3.3V "digital" environment - and this is just one of many ways.
I'd start with an offset trim supply with about ±4mV output range around 0V. The Arduino should be outputting a 10kHz square wave (50% PWM) out of a pin. On the simulation this is marked V1 and sine - disregard the latter. That square wave is fed to the voltage inverter C1-C2-D1-D2. Out of it flows about -2V. OA1 uses the 3.3V as a reference to generate +/-0.8V that is then fed to the divider R6-VR1-R7.

simulate this circuit
Now we can get to the actual amplifier. The sensor - a 0..50μV DC source - is connected between the offset voltage generator and the first-stage amplifier (OA2) input.

simulate this circuit
The 0.1-10Hz noise of the LM358 is several μVp-p, so with a 50μV sensor input, the signal to noise ratio is about 1:10. That noise is, at least on paper, worse than the noise of TL072.
To null out the offset, short the sensor, adjust VR1 so that the output of OA1 is between +0.05V and +0.10V. The offset of subsequent stages doesn't play a role.
The first stage op-amp and its feedback network needs to be kept at a very stable temperature. Or, instead of LM358, use a much better CMOS rail-to-rail I/O op-amp that will have lower noise, much lower offset drift, and also lower initial offset.
The output voltage range is 0.0 to 1.1V. There is no point in making it any wider, since even with an 8-bit ADC, you'll be easily measuring the input op-amp noise. Further amplifying the output won't be useful at all.
We could extend the voltage converter circuit to also generate a positive bias voltage to extend the output range of the last stage to +3V. I wouldn't bother. But it's possible.

The question overall lacks a lot of detail. If you can avoid making an instrumentation amplifier - or using one, you'll usually win performance-wise. Everything else being equal, an in-amp performs quite a bit worse in every aspect compared to an op-amp. If you're measuring a bridge, for example, it's better to control the excitation voltage in a closed loop to keep one arm of the bridge at a constant voltage, and a 2nd op-amp to provide some DC preamplification. Both should be adjacent to the sensor. Then the preamplified output can go down a cable and into a differential ADC input. Modern ADCs have way better CMRR than in-amps, so using the ADC's differential input directly will reject common mode noise from the cable quite nicely (with some caveats).
In-amps built in classical 2- or 3-opamp topologies from discrete parts perform rather abysmally. They illustrate two principles well, though: 1. That of how a given in-amp topology works, and 2. Why integrated in-amps are worth it, if you need the 3-opamp topology. Otherwise, if you have access to the sensor and can locate the op-amps right there, it'll be a win almost always. Extreme environments, such as down-hole electronics that run very hot, may not be very conducive to common approaches. That's why they are usually expensive - the high-temp parts are expensive, and the high-temp design techniques are expensive as well as experience isn't free.

okay, I think I am following you, using the second circuit you sent photos of, could the virtual ground be higher? the final circuit I am working on has an instrumentation amp made of tl072's, that will be connected to an arduino. so, could I use the second system with the 3.3V supply through a voltage divider to make this "virtual ground" ~1.65V so I can use a +5v and gnd supply voltages to the op amps from the arduino? so I dont have to worry as much about hitting the upper limit of output (about 3.5V with those supplys)

The likelihood of making a decent "instrumentation amp" out of TL072 and low-spec parts is slim. Please tell us exactly what you are trying to measure. And no, the virtual ground cannot be much higher because you'll run out of output range. It's already very close to the highest possible with a gain of 10 and a 0.2Vpp signal. Yours is smaller of course.

Basically, making an in-amp out of TL072s is a wee bit more complicated than making separate gain stages and combining them.

I'm also not sure what drove you to use TL072 in a low-voltage circuit. Those TLs are good cheap parts for audio use. Other than that, there's little reason to use them for pretty much anything.
